# Proving a simple inequality on the open unit square?

Tags: inequality

How would you prove algebraically that the assertion $\exists (x,y) \in (0,1)^2. x +y > 1 + xy$ [is false](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%2B%20y%20%3E%20%201%20%2B%20xy,%200%20%3C%20x%20%3C%201,%200%20%3C%20y%20%3C%201)?

Comment: Proving that the inequality false on the unit square is easily done by finding a single point which breaks the inequality. For instance $(0.5,0.5)$ gives $1\not>1.25$.  However, proving that $x+y\leq 1+xy$ is true in the unit square is an entirely different story, and I think that that's what you meant. And i still think this question lacks context and doesn't really deserve all the answers it has gotten.

Comment: @Arthur Please let me know what details are missing from the question so that it can be improved. I do not have any additional context or clarifications to add; the question is rather basic and is intended to invite basic answers.

Comment: @Arthur additionally, I have reworded the question in response to your comment, by clarifying the statement of the assertion. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L-R =x+y-1-xy = x(1-y)-(1-y)= (1-y)(x-1)<0$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the factorization
$$1-x-y+xy=(1-x)(1-y)$$

Now note that:

$0<x<1 \implies 0<1-x<1$

$0<y<1 \implies 0<1-y<1$

Since both are positive,

$$1-x-y+xy>0$$
$$1+xy>x+y$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll just work assuming that $x$ and $y$ can't equal $1$, otherwise the inequality isn't true for $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Squaring them both gets rid of the $xy$ term
$$x+y>1+xy$$
$$x^2+2xy+y^2>1+2xy+x^2y^2$$
$$x^2+y^2>1+x^2y^2$$
Now $x^2+y^2$ is a positive term less or equal to $1$ since it's inside the unit circle. Now since $x^2y^2$ is a positive term the inequality is not true since the left side is less than $1$ and the right is greater than $1$

Comment: I think you mean the inequality is NOT true. You missed "not".

Comment: Whoops thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Hint: move all terms to the same side to get the equivalent inequality $1-x-y+xy<0$, and then factor the expression on the left-hand side.